# I cant install dlib using pip. what is the problem?

Tags: pip, anaconda, python-3.7, dlib

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
>   'C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools,
>   tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-nd2ljdx5'
>   --python-tag cp37
>          cwd: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\   Complete
>   output (53 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build   running
>   build_py   package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a
>   regular file)   running build_ext   Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py",
>   line 120, in get_cmake_version
>         out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
>         **kwargs).stdout
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
>         with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>         restore_signals, start_new_session)
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>         startupinfo)   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py",
>   line 261, in 
>         'Topic :: Software Development',
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py",
>   line 145, in setup
>         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
>         dist.run_commands()
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
>         self.run_command(cmd)
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line
>   192, in run
>         self.run_command('build')
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>         self.distribution.run_command(command)
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
>         self.run_command(cmd_name)
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>         self.distribution.run_command(command)
>       File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py",
>   line 129, in run
>         cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
>       File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py",
>   line 125, in get_cmake_version
>         "\n*******************************************************************\n")   RuntimeError:

---

**CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib**

---

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib   Running setup.py clean for dlib Failed to build dlib Installing collected packages: dlib   Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py'"'"';
**file**='"'"'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8fa9q7wn\install-record.txt'
--single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
    cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py", line 125, in get_cmake_version
    "\n*******************************************************************\n")
RuntimeError:

*******************************************************************
 CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
*******************************************************************

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7ictrqd\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8fa9q7wn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1):

This is your error:

> CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib

Which tells it all. For the compilation to work, you need to install `cmake`.

But, since you are using anaconda, there is no reason to use `pip` to install `dlib`. It is actually not even recommended to use `pip` to install packages to your `conda` environment if it can be avoided. That said, simply use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

to install